# How to use RestKit without response description mapping?

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I have a existing project which is using RestKit and now I need to update some API requests. The problem is I have a post request which doesn't need to care the response body. I just want to know the response status code is 200 or not. So I don't add RKResponseDescriptor then RestKit reports error:"No response descriptors match the response loaded.".How could I send request without any response descriptors? Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use restkit to create the request but then run the request yourself. If restkit isn't running the request then it isn't involved in the response processing.

Comment: Hi, could you please provide more detail? you mean create request operation then start it by self?